# How to store this in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, animation, anime.js

my goal is to store this code:

```
anime.timeline()
        .add({
            targets: '.animate .word',
            scale: [14, 1],
            opacity: [0, 1],
            easing: "easeOutCirc",
            duration: 600,
        });
```

inside of a function that once i'll call it, it will run the the code above.
 I have tried this on:

```
var animate = ()=>{
anime.timeline()
            .add({
                targets: '.animate .word',
                scale: [14, 1],
                opacity: [0, 1],
                easing: "easeOutCirc",
                duration: 600,
            });
};
```

but once I called this, it seems to have an error that says that anime.timline() is not a function.
any ideas?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: `function someFunction() { /*your code here*/ }`

Comment: You don't have function called `anime.timeline` anymore, you have a function called `animate`..

Comment: I have addes the problem above

Comment: yea that is it, ty :)

Comment: make sure you add the [anime](http://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineParameters) script file before your code.

Comment: Done that ty. :)

Comment: You are calling this function by `animate()` now correct? If so, can we see more of this file?

Comment: I have done this one ty :)